# SQL: selecting customers that haven't had an entry in past 2 weeks

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a database that has multiple tables to track customers and our interactions with them, among other things. I'm creating a report using PHP that should display all customers that have an open status and don't have an interaction logged in the pas 2 weeks. I was trying to do a query, then while processing those results it would run another query based on that, but it was very slow and I couldn't get it to work correctly. I think the JOIN function is my answer, but I'm not entirely sure how to implement it.

my tables have these fields:

```
customers: customer_id
customers_marketing_options: customer_id, status
customer_interactions: customer_id, created_on (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)
```

right now, I have it selecting all customers that have an open status. Then with those results, I select all interactions with that customer id, created_on being at most 2 weeks prior, sorting that by the created_on date and selecting the top row (most recent interaction). however, that returns the interaction for customers that have a warm status. However, it doesn't check to see if they have an interaction in the past 2 weeks.

This probably sounds confusing, however any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT cmo.customer_id,
       Max(ci.created_on) as last_interaction
FROM customer_marketing_options cmo
     inner join customer_interactions ci
     on cmo.customer_id = ci.customer_id
WHERE
  cmo.status = 'open'
GROUP By
  cmo.customer_id
HAVING Max(ci.created_on) < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 14 DAY)
```

Comment: Clearly, it was just a having clause +1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT customer_ID, created_on
FROM customer_interactions
WHERE MAX(created_on) <= (now() - INTERVAL 2 week)
  AND ... status stuff ...
GROUP BY customer_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT ci.customer_id, ci.created_on FROM customer_interactions ci
LEFT JOIN customer_interactions ci2
  ON (ci.customer_id = ci2.customer_id AND ci.created_on < ci2.created_on)
JOIN customers_marketing_options cmo
  ON (ci.customer_id = cmo.customer_id AND status = 'Open')
WHERE ci2.created_on IS NULL AND ci.created_on < now() - interval 2 week
```

Check the working example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c964/2).